# UIPopovercontroller detached from UIButton

Tags: xcode, ipad, ios, uibutton, uipopovercontroller

I'm running into a problem with a detached UIPopovercontroller and am hoping someone has seen this behavior before.

My app runs in Landscape mode and offers a number of popover elements using the presentPopoverFromRect call. Some are launched from within the top view while others are presented from a view buried deep in the display.  The popovers seem to work fine if the popover is presented from the upper 2/3rds of the iPad's display however when attempting to launch a popover from the bottom 1/3 of the display the popover is displayed detached from the UIButton.  The x coordinate appears to be correct, however the y coordinate of the popover tends to be in the middle or top of the iPad screen.

I've played around with presenting the popover using a fixed position by creating a CGRect object in the lower 1/3 of the display but when the iPad renders the popover it either renders the popover in the upper 2/3rd of the view or the very bottom of the screen (if I force the CGRect value to a large y value).

At this point I'm out of ideas and hoping someone on the forum has seen this or can make suggestions as to what to try.

Thanks for any and all help,
Wes

Comment: had you set the popoverArrowDirection to use any direction?

Comment: Hi Nevin, thanks for the response.  Yes, the arrow direction is set to UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix my issue and thought that I'd share my solution incase someone else has the same problem.

The solution was to add a call to set the popover size BEFORE calling presentPopoverFromRect.

```
[mySettingsPopoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 320) animated:YES];
[mySettingsPopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:sender.frame inView:self.navigationButtonsView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Before, I wasn't setting the popover content size prior to presenting the popover.  In the viewDidAppear method of the viewcontroller of the popover I was resizing the popover to size to the tableview in the popover.  Apparently by not setting the popovercontentsize before presenting the popover you get undefined behavior including the possibility of having the popover detach from the element that it is suppose to be attached to.

Wes